# Limit of segments ratio in partition of an arc of circle

Tags: geometry

Consider an arc $(AB)$ of a circle $C$ and the partition $(A_i^n)$, where $A_0^n=A$,$A_n^n=B$. The measure of $A_{i-1}^n A_{i}^n$ will be denoted $h_n$.

Now consider the following: Trace the bissector of each angle $A_{i-1}OA_{i}$ and mark the medium point $B_{i}^n$ of the arc $(A_{i-1}^n A_{i}^n)$, then the tangente line $r_i$ to $C$ through $B_i^n$. Consider then the points 
$V_{i}^{n}$ where the line $r_i$ intersects the ray $OA_i^n$, and denote $v_n$ the measure of $V_{i-1}^n V_{i}^n$.

Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{v_n}{h_n} = 1$ .

I believe that if $n \to \infty$, then $V_i^n = A_i^n$ and the limit will be trivial, but I don't quite see how to formalize this argument.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm needing an explanation on why $n \to \infty \Rightarrow V_{i}^{n} = A_{i}^{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By similar triangles you have (see diagram below):
$$
{v_n\over h_n}={R\over\sqrt{R^2-h_n^2/4}},
$$
where $R$ is the radius of $C$.
But $h_n\to 0$ when $n\to+\infty$, so that:
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}{v_n\over h_n}=
\lim_{n\to+\infty}{R\over\sqrt{R^2-h_n^2/4}}=1.
$$
[image]